# Update Excel 2007 with OleDb

Tags: vb.net, excel, oledb

Attempting to execute an update command against an Excel 2007 file gives the error:
**Operation must use an updateable query.**
I'm using System.Data.OleDb with a connection string like this:

```
Dim strConn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=""" & pathToFile & """;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES"""
```

I have tried setting ReadOnly=false but that gives **Could not find installable ISAM.** I have also tried setting Mode=ReadWrite and IMEX=1 which didn't seem to have any effect. My update command is like this:

```
 Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = con.CreateCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [" + sheetName + "] SET [Quantity Error] = 'test' WHERE [Full Name] = 'Mr. Brown White'"
```

where sheetName was obtained from querying the excel schema. Is it possible to do what I am trying to? Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You usually need a $ sign after the worksheet name. Try:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [" + sheetName + "$] SET [Quantity Error] = 'test' WHERE [Full Name] = 'Mr. Brown White'"
```

Names without $ signs are interpreted as named ranges and not as worksheet names

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is usually a permissions issue. Can you read/write to the file if you open it in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Use this connection string this will work

`Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + reportFile + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;\";`

Besides checking the permissions to your Excel file verify if the Extended Properties of the connection string contains the `IMEX=1` expression. If yes, remove it.