# C# Form OleDb Excel Update command for data in textbox and combobox

Tags: c#, excel, oledbcommand

I have a form with textbox and combobox. I am inserting data from those two boxes into excel using OleDb insert into command

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();            

connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
Source=C:\Desktop\Excel\Book1.xlsx; 
Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR = YES'";

connection.Open();

OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
string error = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
command.CommandText = "insert into [Sheet1$] (NAME, MARKS) values('" + 
textBox1.Text + "' , '" + error + "') ";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("data saved");
connection.Close();
```

Now i need update command for updating any previous data in excel.

Comment: You should always use parameters when you want to use user input in an SQL query. Your approach is currently wide open for SQL injection. It might be just excel, but you should make the right approach a habit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update Excel 2007 with OleDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836971/update-excel-2007-with-oledb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UPDATE query would look like this. I am using parameters for the user-provided values, as you should do too in your INSERT:

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.CommandText = "update [Sheet1$] set MARKS = @Marks where NAME = @Name";
command.Paramerers.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Marks", error));
command.Paramerers.Add(new OleDbParameter("@Name", textBox1.Text));
```